# What's the most Pythonic way to deal with a list of nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, reddit

What's the most Pythonic way to identify the different nested dictionary types an API returns so the right type of parsing can be applied?

I'm doing API calls from Reddit to get URLs and I'm getting nested dictionaries with different key names and different structures of nested dictionaries.
I am pulling the URLs I need just fine, but I need a more Pythonic way to identify the different key names and different structures of the nested dictionaries because `if` statements I tried in one `for` loop run into errors because "if" the dictionary does not contain the key I get a `NoneType` error just from the `if` statement "asking" if said key is in the dictionary.

In a few more paragraphs I describe the problem but you may be able to dive into the dictionary examples and my code below and see my problem of not being able to identify one of the three types of dictionaries in one pass. The nested dictionaries do not have the same structures and my code is full of `try`s and what I think redundant `for` loops.

I have a function to handle three types of nested dictionaries. `topics_data` (used below) is a Pandas Dataframe and the column `vid` is a column name in `topics_data` that contains a nested dictionary. Sometimes the object in the `vid` cell is `None` if the post I am reading is not a video post.

There are only three main types of nested dictionaries the API returns (if not `None`). My biggest problem is identifying the first key name without getting a `NoneType` error if I try an `if` statement catch a nested dictionary with the key `reddit_video` that starts with another key such as `oembed` instead. Because of this problem I iterate over the list of nested dictionaries three times for each of the three nested dictionary types. I want to be able to iterate over the list of nested dictionaries once and have each type of nested dictionary be identified and processed in one pass.

Below are examples of the three different types of nested dictionaries I'm getting and the ugly code I have setup now to handle them. The code I have works, but it is ugly. Please dig in and see.

The nested dictionaries...

Nested Dictionary One

```
{'reddit_video': {'fallback_url': 'https://v.redd.it/te7wsphl85121/DASH_2_4_M?source=fallback',
  'height': 480,
  'width': 480,
  'scrubber_media_url': 'https://v.redd.it/te7wsphl85121/DASH_600_K',
  'dash_url': 'https://v.redd.it/te7wsphl85121/DASHPlaylist.mpd?a=1604490293%2CYmQzNDllMmQ4MDVhMGZhODMyYmIxNDc4NTZmYWNlNzE2Nzc3ZGJjMmMzZGJjMmYxMjRiMjJiNDU4NGEzYzI4Yg%3D%3D&v=1&f=sd',
  'duration': 17,
  'hls_url': 'https://v.redd.it/te7wsphl85121/HLSPlaylist.m3u8?a=1604490293%2COTg2YmIxZmVmZGNlYTVjMmFiYjhkMzk5NDRlNWI0ZTY4OGE1NzgxNzUyMDhkYjFiNWYzN2IxYWNkZjM3ZDU2YQ%3D%3D&v=1&f=sd',
  'is_gif': False,
  'transcoding_status': 'completed'}}
```

Nested Dictionary Two

```
{'type': 'gfycat.com',
 'oembed': {'provider_url': 'https://gfycat.com',
  'description': 'Hi! We use cookies and similar technologies ("cookies"), including third-party cookies, on this website to help operate and improve your experience on our site, monitor our site performance, and for advertising purposes. By clicking "Accept Cookies" below, you are giving us consent to use cookies (except consent is not required for cookies necessary to run our site).',
  'title': 'Protestors in Hong Kong are cutting down facial recognition towers.',
  'type': 'video',
  'author_name': 'Gfycat',
  'height': 600,
  'width': 600,
  'html': '<iframe class="embedly-embed" src="https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fgfycat.com%2Fifr%2Fedibleunrulyargentineruddyduck&display_name=Gfycat&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgfycat.com%2Fedibleunrulyargentineruddyduck-hong-kong-protest&image=https%3A%2F%2Fthumbs.gfycat.com%2FEdibleUnrulyArgentineruddyduck-size_restricted.gif&key=ed8fa8699ce04833838e66ce79ba05f1&type=text%2Fhtml&schema=gfycat" width="600" height="600" scrolling="no" title="Gfycat embed" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>',
  'thumbnail_width': 280,
  'version': '1.0',
  'provider_name': 'Gfycat',
  'thumbnail_url': 'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/EdibleUnrulyArgentineruddyduck-size_restricted.gif',
  'thumbnail_height': 280}}
```

Nested Dictionary Three

```
{'oembed': {'provider_url': 'https://gfycat.com',
  'description': 'Hi! We use cookies and similar technologies ("cookies"), including third-party cookies, on this website to help operate and improve your experience on our site, monitor our site performance, and for advertising purposes. By clicking "Accept Cookies" below, you are giving us consent to use cookies (except consent is not required for cookies necessary to run our site).',
  'title': 'STRAYA! Ski-roos.   Stephan Grenfell for Australian Geographic',
  'author_name': 'Gfycat',
  'height': 338,
  'width': 600,
  'html': '<iframe class="embedly-embed" src="https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fgfycat.com%2Fifr%2Fhairyvibrantamericanratsnake&display_name=Gfycat&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgfycat.com%2Fhairyvibrantamericanratsnake-snow-kangaroos&image=https%3A%2F%2Fthumbs.gfycat.com%2FHairyVibrantAmericanratsnake-size_restricted.gif&key=ed8fa8699ce04833838e66ce79ba05f1&type=text%2Fhtml&schema=gfycat" width="600" height="338" scrolling="no" title="Gfycat embed" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>',
  'thumbnail_width': 444,
  'version': '1.0',
  'provider_name': 'Gfycat',
  'thumbnail_url': 'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/HairyVibrantAmericanratsnake-size_restricted.gif',
  'type': 'video',
  'thumbnail_height': 250},
 'type': 'gfycat.com'}
```

My function to handle these three types of nested dictionaries. `topics_data` is a Pandas Dataframe and the column `vid` is a column name in `topics_data` that contains a nested dictionary or it is `None`.

```
def download_vid(topics_data, ydl_opts):
    for i in topics_data['vid']:
        try:
            if i['reddit_video']:
                B = i['reddit_video']['fallback_url']
                with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                    ydl.download([B])

                print(B)
        except:
            pass
    for n, i in enumerate(topics_data['vid']):
        try:
            if i['type'] == 'gfycat.com':
                C = topics_data.loc[n]['vid']['oembed']['thumbnail_url'].split('/')[-1:][0].split('-')[0]
                C = 'https://giant.gfycat.com/'+ C +'.mp4'
                sub = str(topics_data.loc[n]['subreddit']).lower()
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(C,
                                           '/media/iii/Q2/tor/Reddit/Subs/'+sub+'/'+C.split('/')[-1:][0])

                print(C)
        except:
            pass
    for i in topics_data['vid']:
        try:
            if i['oembed']['thumbnail_url']:
                D = topics_data.loc[n]['vid']['oembed']['thumbnail_url'].split('/')[-1:][0].split('-')[0]
                D = 'https://giant.gfycat.com/'+ D +'.mp4'
                sub = str(topics_data.loc[n]['subreddit']).lower()
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(D, '/media/iii/Q2/tor/Reddit/Subs/'+sub+'/'+D.split('/')[-1:][0])
                print(D)
        except:
            pass
```

After writing this code I've seen the `if` statements are redundant because it will either `try` and succeed to parse `topics_data.loc[n]['vid']['oembed']` if it is possible or not inside each `try` block.
Don't get bogged down in how the nested dictionary is parsed because that's not really my issue. My problem is mainly with how to identify which type of nested dictionary the iterator has. I would assume this can all be handled inside one `for` loop instead of three.
One last problem is occasionally there is a forth, fifth, or sixth type of dictionary I'm not interested in parsing because they are too rare.

This last block of code is probably not required but I am adding it just to  make the question complete. My function that identifies and parses the dictionaries also takes in the parameters for youtube-dl.

```
def my_hook(d):
    if d['status'] == 'finished':
        print('Done downloading, now converting ...')

def yt_dl_opts(topics_data):
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestvideo+bestaudio/37/22/18/best',
        'merge': 'mp4',
        'noplaylist' : True,        
        'progress_hooks': [my_hook],
        'outtmpl' : '/media/iii/Q2/tor/Reddit/Subs/'+ str(topics_data.loc[0]['subreddit']).lower()+'/%(id)s'
    }
    return ydl_opts
```

UPDATE
Here's the answer to the question with help from Neil. Just adding to make the Q and A more clear for future generations.
Everything is still wrapped in a `try: except: pass` because there are still a few random, and always new dic structures returned. I write a loop to count the video results that are not `None` and count all the videos successfully downloaded with `os.walk`.

```
def download_vid(topics_data, ydl_opts):
    y_base = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='
    for n, i in enumerate(topics_data['vid']):
        try:
            if 'type' in i:
                if 'youtube.com' in i[n]['type']:
                    print('This is a Youtube Video')
                    A = i['oembed']['html'].split('embed/')[1].split('?')[0]
                    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                        ydl.download([A])
                    print(y_base+A)

            if 'reddit_video' in i:
                print('This is a reddit_video Video')
                B = i['reddit_video']['fallback_url']
                with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                    ydl.download([B])
                print(B)

            if 'type' in i:
                if 'gfycat.com' in i[n]['type']:
                    print('This is a type, gfycat Video')
                    C = topics_data.loc[n]['vid']['oembed']['thumbnail_url'].split('/')[-1:][0].split('-')[0]
                    C = 'https://giant.gfycat.com/'+ C +'.mp4'
                    sub = str(topics_data.loc[n]['subreddit']).lower()
                    urllib.request.urlretrieve(C,
                                       '/media/iii/Q2/tor/Reddit/Subs/'+sub+'/'+C.split('/')[-1:][0])
                print(C)

            if 'oembed' in i:
                print('This is a oembed, gfycat Video')
                D = topics_data.loc[n]['vid']['oembed']['thumbnail_url'].split('/')[-1:][0].split('-')[0]
                D = 'https://giant.gfycat.com/'+ D +'.mp4'
                sub = str(topics_data.loc[n]['subreddit']).lower()
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(C, '/media/iii/Q2/tor/Reddit/Subs/'+sub+'/'+D.split('/')[-1:][0])
                print(D)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Something like [schema](https://pypi.org/project/schema/) will allow you to both parse and validate in one go.

Comment: Your download_vid function has also become a bit of a god function. I would write three more functions to handle the actual downloading and requests and all that, and just let this function focus on accessing the data from the request. Would be less confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Realised OP's text was dealing with a non-unique lookup. Added a paragraph to describe how to do that.

If you find yourself looping over a list of dictionaries multiple times to perform a lookup, restructure the list into a dictionary so that the lookup is a key. For example this:

```
a = [{"id": 1, "value": "foo"}, {"id": 2, "value": "bar"}]
for item in a:
    if item["id"] == 1:
        print(item["value"])
```

Can become this:

```
a = [{"id": 1, "value": "foo"}, {"id": 2, "value": "bar"}]
a = {item["id"]: item for item in a} # index by lookup field

print(a[1]["value"]) # no loop
... # Now we can continue to loopup by id eg a[2] without a loop
```

If it is a non-unique lookup you can do similar:

```
indexed = {}
a = [{"category": 1, "value": "foo"}, {"category": 2, "value": "bar"}, {"category": 1, "value": "baz"}]
for item in a: # This loop only has to be executed once
    if indexed.get(item["category"], None) is not None:
        indexed[item["category"]].append(item)
    else:
        indexed[item["category"]] = [item]

# Now we can do:
all_category_1_data = indexed[1]
all_category_2_data = indexed[2]
```

If you get index error, use default dictionary indexing to handle more easily

```
if a.get(1, None) is not None:
    print(a[1]["value"])
else:
    print("1 was not in the dictionary")
```

There's nothing "Pythonic" about this IMO though if the API is returning lists that you need to loop over it's just probably a badly designed API

Update: Okay, I'll attempt to fix your code:

```
def download_vid(topics_data, ydl_opts):
    indexed_data = {'reddit': [], 'gfycat': [], 'thumbnail': []}

    for item in topics_data['vid']:
        if item.get('reddit_video', None) is not None:
            indexed_data['reddit'].append(item)
        elif item.get('type', None) == "gfycat.com":
            indexed_data['gfycat'].append(item)
        elif item.get('oembed', None) is not None:
            if item['oembed'].get('thumbnail_url', None) is not None:
                indexed_data['thumbnail'].append(item)

    for k, v in indexed_data.items():
        assert k in ('reddit_video', 'gfycat', 'thumbnail')
        if k == 'reddit_video':
            B = v['reddit_video']['fallback_rul']
            ...
        elif k == 'gfycat':
            C = v['oembed']['thumbnail_url']
            ...
        elif k == 'thumbnail':
            D = v['oembed']['thumbnail_url']
            ...
```

Just incase it is unclear why this is better:

- OP looped over topics_data['vid'] three times. I did it twice.
- More importantly, if more topics are added, I still only do twice. OP would have to loop again.
- No exception handling.
- Each group of objects is now indexed. So OP can do, eg indexed_data['gfycat'] to get all those objects if needed and this is a hash table lookup so its fast

Comment: Ah I shouldn't have done that in the first example. But that ISNT all I did.

Comment: Fixed that was a typo. see now @KennyOstrom

Comment: Thanks. (this message will self-destruct)

Comment: I'm having trouble checking yes or no and passing over the first key in the nested dic without an error (if it is not None). The `if, is not None` works fine if it is or is not but I'm still having trouble identifying a specific key like `oembed` (from the OP). When I try to check if it's there in a block that can parse it I get an error if `oembed` is not the first key. I appreciate the answer, but your dics have the same first key for all examples.

Comment: I'm hesitant to edit your code. Feels like this may be better on code review forumn. But I also don't know what you're saying now. I'll show this on your code if you're going remain active on this question.

Comment: I understand your question now. Basically, the long of the short is that, if you didn't tell me these three jsons came from the same API, I wouldn't have guessed. They do not have the same schema. Which means a little bit of manual interference is necessary and there probably isn't an elegant solution. The solution I posted in the edited answer above is better but still a bit ugly.

Comment: Nice. Right before I booted up my computer I thought the solution was to use `if` and `in` to detect which schema I'm dealing with. I'm pretty sure I can get everything with one iteration over the list of dics with it. This really is what the API returns. Maybe they have it this way to dissuade people from easily scraping Reddit. Luckily for me `youtube-dl` merges the audio and video. I would not be able to figure out how to get both without it.

Comment: In hindsight I should have asked this question by making a list of three simple dictionaries that each started with a different key and a loop trying to identify each one. I agree I really clouded things by putting things up here, but I guess it kind of worked out regardless.